# wxPython: wx.SpinCtrl border management

Tags: python, layout, wxpython

I'm trying to create a basic date-selector/calendar in wxPython. So far I've managed
to add all the necessary widgets to my grid, but I'm struggling to get them 
positioned properly. Although there are numerous things I don't fully understand, 
I'm getting particularly frustrated with the wx.SpinCtrl widget, which seems to be 
surrounded by a massive border despite the fact that none is specified. Can anyone
tell me how to remove this? I want the spin control to be just a couple of pixels 
away from the top of the frame, with the text 'February' the same number of pixels away
from the bottom of the control. I've tried all manner of approaches but none seem to
have any effect.

```
import wx
import calendar

MONTH_NAME_AS_KEY = {"January":1, "February":2, "March":3, "April":4, "May":5, "June":6,
                 "July":7, "August":8, "September":9, "October":10, "November":11,
                 "December":12}

def getMonthNumber(nameAsString):
    return MONTH_NAME_AS_KEY.get(nameAsString)


class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title): 
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title,size=(300, 350))

        self.InitUI() 
        self.Centre() 
        self.Show()

    def InitUI(self):

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        fgs = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=2, cols=2)

        # fgs 1: blank space
        filler = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, label="")
        fgs.Add(filler)

        # fgs 2: creating containers
        vSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        yearNavigationBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        monthNavigationBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        # year navigation
        sc = wx.SpinCtrl(self.panel,-1, "", size=(70,70))
        sc.SetRange(1980,2060)
        sc.SetValue(2011)

        yearNavigationBox.Add(sc, wx.ALL, wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP)

        # month navigation
        monthDown = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, label="<")    
        monthUp = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, label=">")      


        monthName = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, label="February")  

        monthNavigationBox.Add(monthDown)
        monthNavigationBox.Add(monthName)
        monthNavigationBox.Add(monthUp)

        vSizer.Add(yearNavigationBox)
        vSizer.Add(monthNavigationBox)

        fgs.Add(vSizer)

        # fgs 3: the date of the month writ large
        date = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, label='31', style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        dateFont = wx.Font(150, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        date.SetFont(dateFont)

        fgs.Add(date)


        # fgs 4: the date grid
        dateSquareSizer = wx.GridSizer(rows=6, cols=7, hgap=1, vgap=6)

        dayFont = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
        for item in days:
            day = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, label=item)
            day.SetFont(dayFont)
            dateSquareSizer.Add(day)    

        y = 2012
        m = getMonthNumber(monthName.GetLabel())    

        gridData = list(calendar.Calendar().itermonthdays(y, m))
        while len(gridData)<43: gridData.append(0)

        for i in gridData:
            if i == 0: i=""
            square = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, label=str(i))
            square.SetFont(dayFont)
            dateSquareSizer.Add(square, wx.ID_ANY)      

        fgs.Add(dateSquareSizer)

        mainSizer.Add(fgs, wx.ALL, 2)

        self.panel.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        mainSizer.Fit(self)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App() 
    Example(None, title='') 
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't quite have the sizer's Add signature correct. It should be sizer.Add(widget, proportion, flags, border)

You keep skipping the proportion and are not specifying a border at all. If you did this instead:

```
yearNavigationBox.Add(sc, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP, 5)
```

It will put the spinner 5 pixels below the top of the frame (or whatever widget is added before this one). You have a few other places where you're skipping the proportion flag and putting other random stuff in its place. You'll want to go through and change that. Here are a couple tutorials:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/05/18/a-wxpython-sizers-tutorial/
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/UsingSizers

Comment: Thanks Mike, have gone through these tutorials and hopefully have a slightly better grip on widget positioning.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you got it figured out.